# Firebase Cloud Messaging сообщения в спящем режиме телефона

Tags: android, push-уведомления, firebase-android, fcm

Разрабатываю приложение на Android Xamarin, интегрировал Firebase Cloud Messaging для Push уведомлений. Всё прекрасно работает, до тех пор пока смартфон не уйдет в сон.
Сообщение приходит только тогда, когда разблокируешь телефон. То есть при глубоком сне сообщение не отобразится даже если ты включишь экран телефона. Только при разблокировке.

В настройках приложения установлено, не экономить заряд аккумулятора, но я так понимаю это на доставку уведомления это не влияет, т.к. сообщение доходит даже при убитом приложении.
Как решить данную проблему? Всякого рода мессенджеры, соцсети и почта доставляют пуш уведомления в спящем режиме.

Поведение одинаковое для 11 и 14 Android, тестирую на дешевом китайском телефоне и Pixel 7 Pro

Comment: а вы флаг важности какой устанавливаете?

Comment: @Style-7 У самого уведомления 
.SetPriority(NotificationCompat.PriorityMax)
но это я так понял устаревший метод, логика перешла в настройки самого канала уведомлений:

Importance = NotificationImportance.Max 
По документации на офф.сайте Max и High на сколько я понял примерно одинаковы

Или имеется ввиду приоритет в FCM?

Comment: да, в канале. Система должна уведомлять сама пользователя в соответствии с его настройками.

Answer (score 0):

Начиная с Android 11 (API 30) доступен метод [`Notification.Builder.setFullScreenIntent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#setFullScreenIntent(android.app.PendingIntent,%20boolean)) который выводит `Intent` поверх экрана блокировки как раз на тот случай когда нужно срочно припадочно обратить на себя внимание даже при выключенном экране. Возможно это ваш случай.

Нужно также задекларировать разрешение [`USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT).